# Titanium Alloy : 'Uncaught TypeError: Ti.UI.createview is not a function'

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

Recently I installed a new environnement Linux with appcelerator.

I have a probleme when I compile my projetc :

"[ERROR] V8Exception: Exception occurred at /alloy/controllers/index.js:1: Uncaught TypeError: Ti.UI.createview is not a function"

My setup :
- Alloy : 1.9.4
- Appc : 6.0.0
- Ti : 5.0.10
- npm : 3.5.2
- nodeJs : 4.2.6

Sdk :
6.0.0.GA and 4.0.0 GA (I use 6.0.0.GA)

When I check my environement configuration with ti, all is okay.
Java is okay too.

I have juste create a controller "page", and "menu"
I create juste a basic function, see example follow :

menu.js

```
$.myLabel.text = "foo";

function show() {
 alert("test !");
}
```

menu.xml

```
<Alloy>
 <View id="menu">
    <View class="container">

        <View class="menuItem" onTouchstart="show">
            <Label id="myLabel" class="logo" class="font"/>
        </View>

    </View>
 </View>
</Alloy>
```

page.js

```
$.labelInfo1.text = "bar";

function setInfo() {
 alert("infos !");
}
```

page.xml

```
<Alloy>
 <view class="container">
    <view id="page" class="item">
        <label id="labelInfo1" class="font"/>
    </view>
 </view>
</Alloy>
```

I think, Alloy don't found the ressource for create view ? Or I missing a thing ?...
I found a similar probleme :

[Titanium Alloy ListView XML Uncaught TypeError: Object #<UI> has no method 'createTemplates'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036648/titanium-alloy-listview-xml-uncaught-typeerror-object-ui-has-no-method-crea)

I try to update Alloy with differents versions, but no succes.

Answer (score 1):

I was gone in a totally different direction, while the problem was right befor my eyes...

From Facebook group "Appcelerator Titanium Developers Group"

" Guilherme Moreira said : In your index file, there is a line trying to create a view. The correct function name is createView, camel case like "

" Addiel Juárez said : this mistake is in the view on page.xml

the correct form is
 "

Thank you very much guys ! I search since the beginning of the weekend my error!